# Is this AES GCM + asymmetric schema secure?

Tags: aes, public-key, ecies

I want to use the asymmetric encription offered by a tool to encrypt my files and I would like to know if the following encryption process works, regardless of perhaps not optimal use.

- Generate a `32-bytes-random-key` inside the browser with `window.crypto.getRandomValues`
- use [sjcl crypto library](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/) for:

  - choosing AES algorythm `cipher.aes`
  - generating 4 words random IV vector `random.randomWords(4, 0)`
  - encrypting a file in GCM mode `mode.gcm.encrypt` (tag 128 bits)
  - concating IV and encrypted output producing the `binaryFile1`
- use [NaCl Networking and Cryptography library](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/), through a tool that implements ECIES, for:

  - generating an `encryptionKeypair` using `nacl.box.keyPair.fromSecretKey`
  - encrypting the above `32-bytes-random-key` with the `ephemeralPublicKey` (using the `x25519` part of the schema `x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305`) producing the `binaryFile2`, a bundle containing the encrypted AES key and, among other metadata, the `ephemeralPublicKey`.
- concat `binaryFile2` + `a-separator` + `binaryFile1` producing `finalBinaryFile`
- keep the `finalBinaryFile` on the cloud until it is necessary to download it and then decrypt it through the reverse process using the `secretKey` I own.

To encrypt the files I could directly use the symmetric key keeping it safe but I would like to use a DB of shared static public keys, whose trustness I can assume valid.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I made the question explicit in the title. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use well-maintained programs like Veracrypt or libraries like the [age](https://github.com/FiloSottile/age) (_age is a simple, modern and secure file encryption tool, format, and Go library_.)

Comment: Complete reviews of cyptographic protocols and schemes is off topic. Using ECIES to encrypt a secret key is a bit spurious; you could use the key agreement part itself to establish a key. Of course, you'd also need to send the ephemeral public key for ECIES, something that is missing in your protocol. I don't see how you've established the static key pair of the receiver or how that public key is trusted, so the description is certainly not without fault nor complete.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks Maarten. Actually I forgot to mention that in the `binaryFile2` there is also the ephemeral publick key so I will update the question. I am aware that I am asking about the validity regardless to the  process of registration of the static key pair and relative trustness.

Answer (score 2):

NaCL provides a set of [`crypto_box`](https://nacl.cr.yp.to/box.html) methods which do this all in one go. Libsodium provides an even easier set of [`crypto_box_easy`](https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/authenticated_encryption) methods.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, My implementation has to be in javascript so I am just using a wrap of NaCl set that offers and manages key pair generations.

Comment: There are JS bindings for libsodium as well.